# OpenGl memory management on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management, opengl-es

I have a UITableView with custom Cells. These cells are containing each an OpenGL drawing (a graph chart). When I scroll the table and the cells become hidden, the cells begin the process of destroying objects, like GLViewController and GLView. As you know GLView has this method: destroyFramebuffer which clears the allocated buffer for OpenGL drawings. 
**My problem occurs when I try to scroll the table very-very fast.** 
Tell me please is this the problem of the framework, which does not manage to clear buffers or how could I solve this thing??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's damn bad idea to have multiple GL views in table cells.
Each GL view allocates a lot of memory, and destroying GL buffers also tooks some time, what you can see during fast scrolling.
You should redesign your application to use only one GL view (for example, make it hidden, build graphs on it, catch image to UIImage, and show only it in table cell).

Comment: I can't do this, cause when a graph is being drawn it has an animation, and there are several different types of graphs on it, so the idea of redesigning is not actual.

Comment: The next idea is to show GL view on table cell only after scrolling is stopped or slowed down.